# React. How can I insert a Grid into a TabPanel without warnings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

Question is self explanatory. I'm using Tabs from Material-UI so that I can render different Grids depending on user's choice. Each panel should contain a Grid with various text fields and components. Problem is that I get a warning saying:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): div cannot appear as a descendant of p.

Below is the code:

```js
<Grid item md={10} xs={10} className={classes.divStyle}>
  {categories.map((category, i) => (
    <TabPanel value={value} index={i} key={`tabpanel-${i}`}>
      <Grid p={3}>
      </Grid>
    </TabPanel>
  ))};
</Grid>
```

How could I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you return a <div> as top level component in your <TabPanel>? If you do you may think to replace it with a fragment using empty angle brackets <></>

Comment: what is the `p` attribute of the `Grid` supposed to do ? I can't see that in the [grid api documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *basically* correct (assuming that you have your here not shown TabContext, Tab, value, etc.).

Check if you have a parent component that renders as a `<p>` tag, e.g. by using the browsers code inspection.

A common source of this error seems to be a parent `<Typography>` element, which renders as a `<p>` tag by default. This can be changed by e.g. `<Typography component="div">`. Alternatively the Typography element might be better used further down the tree, i.e. not as a parent, but more like the same way as you would use the p-tag.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering typically occurs when a div element is nested within a `<p>` element.

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): div cannot appear as a descendant of
> p

If your `TabPanel` component returns `<p>` element, then remove it or move further down the tree and your problem will be gone. This can help you avoid the nesting issue altogether